# Partial orders: Prove transitive and irreflective is equivalent to asymmetric

Tags: order-theory, symmetry

Given set $S$ and binary relation $R \subseteq S \times S$, *let*:

- $R$ is *irreflexive* iff $\{(a,a)|a\in S\} \cap R$ is empty
- $R$ is *asymmetric* iff $(a,b) \in R \implies (b,a) \notin R$
- $R$ is *transitive* iff $(a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R \implies (a,c) \in R$

For any *transitive* $R$, prove *irreflexive* is equivalent to *asymmetric*.

[This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3c4d/5e71464107b1cc612ba2c3a6a1c7aeb78007.pdf) paper, at Lemma 1.1(iv), says the proof is "obvious." However, it seems trivial to construct a counterexample, e.g., a complete digraph. Or, *let*:

$S \equiv \{ a,b,c \}$ and $R \equiv \{(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(a,c),(c,a)\}$

Here $R$ appears to me to be *transitive*, *irreflexive* but yet *symmetric*. What am I missing?

Comment: We can say $R$ is *transitive* only when **forall** $a,b,c$ we have $(a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R \implies (a,c) \in R$. Nowhere it was way that $a,b,c$ need to be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $R$ is not transitive, because $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R$ but $(a,a)\notin R.$

Comment: I knew it was something simple.